# My cdh5.2 cluster get FileNotFoundException when running hbase MR jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, cloudera-cdh

My cdh5.2 cluster has a problem to run hbase MR jobs.

For example, I added the hbase classpath into the hadoop classpath:

```
vi /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

add the line:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase classpath:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"
```

And when I am running:
`hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar rowcounter "mytable"`

I get the following exception:

```
14/12/09 03:44:02 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://clusterName/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://clusterName/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1083)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1075)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1075)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter.main(RowCounter.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:153)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, The problem was environment issue:
When I added the below jars into /usr/lib/hadoop/lib. all worked fine

```
hbase-client-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
hbase-common-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
hbase-protocol-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
hbase-server-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
hbase-prefix-tree-0.98.6-cdh5.2.1.jar
hadoop-core-2.5.0-mr1-cdh5.2.1.jar
htrace-core-2.04.jar
```

My machine has the following rpms in it:

```
>> rpm -qa | grep cdh
zookeeper-3.4.5+cdh5.2.1+84-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.13.el6.x86_64
hadoop-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
hbase-regionserver-0.98.6+cdh5.2.1+64-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.9.el6.x86_64
cloudera-cdh-5-0.x86_64
bigtop-utils-0.7.0+cdh5.2.1+0-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.13.el6.noarch
bigtop-jsvc-0.6.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.13.el6.x86_64
parquet-1.5.0+cdh5.2.1+38-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12.el6.noarch
hadoop-hdfs-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
hadoop-mapreduce-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
hadoop-0.20-mapreduce-tasktracker-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
hbase-0.98.6+cdh5.2.1+64-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.9.el6.x86_64
avro-libs-1.7.6+cdh5.2.1+69-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.13.el6.noarch
parquet-format-2.1.0+cdh5.2.1+6-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.noarch
hadoop-yarn-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
hadoop-hdfs-datanode-2.5.0+cdh5.2.1+578-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.14.el6.x86_64
```

I still wonder which rpm is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Even I have the same problem with CDH 5.2.0. as a work around, 
I manually copied the jar file in to hdfs, then exceptions are not coming

Comment: yes I aware of this solution, but I have many hbase jobs and this is not scale.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the file manually to HDFS, you can add the hbase library path to the **.bashrc** file. Add the lib folder in hbase to the CLASSPATH. 
Also, add the classpath of hbase to HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

Your **.bashrc** file should contain the following:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase mapredcp`

export CLASSPATH=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/*
```

Note: The CLASSPATH should point to the lib folder of your hbase installation folder. Use the following to compile and run your java code.

```
javac Example.java
java -classpath $CLASSPATH:. Example
```